# How to set the sliding DIV responsive to the size of the image width

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have the following HTML which had an image and displays a caption when hovered:

```
<div style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #cccccc; padding: 20px; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="cap-bot">
        <img src="http://appcenter.clickmeeting.com/uploads/2014/05/google-calendar-logo1.gif" alt="" />
        <figcaption>CALENDAR EVENTS</figcaption>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cap-bot {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left; /* removing this centers the image */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
figcaption {
    width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #e55302;
  background: rgba(229,83,2,0.90);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
}
div:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}

.cap-bot:before { bottom: 10px; left: 10px; }
.cap-bot figcaption { left: 0; bottom: -30%;}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption { bottom: 0; }
```

I want to center the image and the caption to be displayed only on top of the image and not the entire DIV.

The `float: left` displays the caption only on the image but when that is removed the image is centered but the caption appears on the entire DIV.

JSFidle: http://jsfiddle.net/69td39ha/3/

Please help me modify the code so that that the image is centered and the caption appears the width of the image (with no fixed dimension set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/69td39ha/4/

Use `display:inline-block` for `.cap-bot` and for parent `text-align:center`

Moved your styles out

```css
.cap {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: Center;
}
.cap-bot {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
}
figcaption {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #e55302;
  background: rgba(229, 83, 2, 0.90);
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
div:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
.cap-bot:before {
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
.cap-bot figcaption {
  left: 0;
  bottom: -30%;
}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption {
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cap">
  <div class="cap-bot">
    <img src="http://appcenter.clickmeeting.com/uploads/2014/05/google-calendar-logo1.gif" alt="" />
    <figcaption>CALENDAR EVENTS</figcaption>
  </div>
</div>
```